# How do I look up the Unicode # for a given character on Lion?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, unicode

How do you find the Unicode number representation for a given character in Lion?

On Mac OS X 10.6 when hovering the mouse cursor over for example the ⌘ symbol in the "Character Viewer" a tool tip would be displayed containing something like:

> Unicode: 2318
>
> UTF8: E2 8c 98

That behavior appears to no longer work on Lion's "Character Viewer"

Comment: NOTE: I am running Mac OS X Version 10.7.0, if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code points should be shown in the right sidebar *if you've enabled the Unicode category from the Customize List… sheet*.

[image]

Comment: On Lion? Are you sure? Does not look like it on my machine.

Comment: How did you get the Unicode to show up there?  I just see on the right side "PLACE OF INTEREST SIGN" and then immediately below it the "Add to Favorites" button.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen It seems to depend on the Unicode category (which corresponds to the All Characters view on 10.6) being shown in the sidebar.

Comment: Perfect, a right under the surface gem, even better than 10.6 now, thanks!

Comment: Oh, I see … that is just amazingly non-intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the character, select the one choice from the popup menu: Copy character info. Then paste somewhere. Not as easy as it used to be.